# Is the union of two spans a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

So say you have A = $<u_1,u_2>$ and B = $<u_3>$

If you have A $\cup$ B does that = A + B?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the span of $(1,0)$ is a line and the span of $(0,1)$ is another line. The union consist of two intersecting lines that is not a subspace.

Comment: How would you prove they are not a subspace?

Comment: That set is not closed under addition. Note that $(1,0)+(0,1)=(1,1)$ is not in such a set.

Comment: But aren't we talking about a span? Therefore couldn't (1,1) be written as a linear combination of (1,0) and (0,1)?

Comment: $A\cup B$ is not a span, in the case above. If your question is if $\mbox{span}\{A,B\}=A+B$ then the answer is yes. But this is a different question.

Comment: Sorry I assumed A $\cup$ B would be a span. Why wouldn't it? Isn't the union of two spans a span itself?

Comment: No, as the example above shows. Think of it geometrically. The image you have of the set is a cross: $+$ (two perpendicular lines in this case). This is not a subspace of the plane. Then, translate you geometric intuition to algebra. Since it is not closed under addition it is not a vector subspace.

Comment: I think I get it a little more now, What would be a correct proof for it not being closed under addition for a general 2 dimensional vector space?

Comment: It is not a proof. To refute that the union of spans is not a subspace you need to give a counterexample. The one above is valid. You can think of different examples.

Comment: I see,I know it is not closed under addition but would this be closed under multiplication by scalar? I would be led to think it would be because if you have scalar  $l \in \Bbb R$ then $l_1$(1,0) + $l_2$(0,1) is in the set right?

Comment: It is closed under multiplication by scalar. If $\vec{v}\in A\cup B$ then $\lambda \vec{v}\in A\cup B.$ But, note that $l_1(1,0) + l_2(0,1)$ is not in the set, unless $l_1=0$ or $l_2=0.$ In other case, it would be closed under addition.